# Can't access USB memory stick after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, wine, openoffice.org

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and all was good. I could read from memory stick and save to memory stick. Usb type.
Now after installing Wine & Brasero I cant access the drive to save files or retrieve them.

I get this message;

```
Error saving the document ebay_pricing_for_April_2020_5th_April_2021:
Object not accessible.
The object cannot be accessed
due to insufficient user rights.
```

What's changed? How can I get round it? All my early files are on here, to move back over to the new computer os.

Comment: Properly unmount and remount the USB stick using your normal method to do both. If that doesn't solve the problem, then edit your question above to clearly explain to us the process you use to unmount and remount the USB stick.

Comment: please explain how to do this. It reads ok in the documents folder and I can view the documents on the usb all ok

Comment: How do you normally unmount or eject the USB stick when you wish to take it out of the machine?

Comment: push mem stick into pc tower. Ubuntu recognizes it and an icon appears on desktop. Click on icon and the contents of the mem stick are displayed. Is this correct?

Comment: Right. When a USB stick becomes read-only, it usually just needs to be ejected and reinserted. If it happens regularly, then try putting the USB stick into a different USB port. If it continues to happen regularly, then replace the USB stick (they wear out). If all USB sticks are always read-only every time you insert them, then there is an Ubuntu ownership or permission issue that we can help sort out.

Comment: tried. usb properties are showing; the permissions of "my USB driv" could not be determined

Comment: Try it in a different USB port

Comment: Think you have sorted it. The usb memory stick must be old, and gone to read only. Real shame. I have had it for many years. Before upgrading to 18.04, I bought a new usb, which on putting it in the pc was very tight. I kind of think its made the socket too lose now for the old usb mem stick. The new one is saving all ok, so I think better buy a few spares.

Comment: are there any commands in terminal to check if its broke?

Comment: The problem with "check if it's broke" is that it must be broken in just the right way to fail whatever the test is. I can check my bicycle for 20 different functions, but that 21st will still make it un-ridable. Seems like you have encountered one of the most common deaths for older USB sticks - cannot write anymore. You are wise to migrate your data to a fresh device.